# How to 100% turn off Google personalization for search?

Tags: search

I have problem that me (I'm in Europe) and my college (he is Europe) are getting different results for a search a Google query even though we use the following:

- we added `&pws=0` to query
- we use browser in incognito mode.

Is there any way to turn off personalization completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be personalizing based on your location.  You can get around this by going through a proxy (dreaded and unacceptable answer, I know). Google doesn't provide an easy option to disable it.

Try these Yoast plugins:
http://yoast.com/tools/seo/disable-personalized-search-plugin/

Or this Chrome extension:
http://www.redflymarketing.com/internet-marketing-tools/google-global/

Google allows you to set your search area as large as a country. By default, I set mine for the United States to remove any local bias that creeps into my results.

Answer (score 0):

try go to the preference page and see if you and your colleague have different settings.
http://www.google.com/preferences

Comment: We are using browser in incognito mode, so of course preference page is not averrable.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a different browser to get an "unpersonalized" search.  There are some browsers that already claim to do this, but I haven't tested them myself...

There may be the problem of the search not being as complete as Google can *'sometimes'* be.  Google is most famous for it's search engine because of how it worked differently from other engines at the time it came out.  This may be more or less the same now, or other companies may have caught up - I'm not sure.

One such engine goes by the ridiculous name "DuckDuckGo."  It is the first result to show up "for me" when searching "unfiltered web search engines".

Other than that, you may try contacting Google representatives to get answers more directly.